# Responsive web design and fixed margins

Tags: css, responsive-design

What is the current best practice regarding responsive web design with fixed width margins?

When I try `margin-left: 80px;` in my **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80351/22rL4eq6/)**, it pushes the screen width out so that it throws my percentage-based width styling off. How do I fix this?

In case it's relevant, I'm developing for a website that will only be viewed via Chrome on the desktop, by the way.

Comment: How can you make this responsive when you use a pixel width on body??

Comment: @WimMertens I thought that, at bottom, pixel sizes need to be specified at some point so that percentage values for child divs can be calculated? If I'm mistaken about that please let me know.

Comment: That applies only to height. But don't add a width to body.

Comment: Thanks for the information @WimMertens. I've updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: No problem. By default all block elements have a width of 100%. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I basically want the same sort of responsive resizing that takes place if `margin-left: 80px` is commented out but with a 80px fixed space on the left when the resizing takes place.

Comment: @user5508297: Check out my answer and JSFiddle. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% - 160px)` in this case, I have updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/22rL4eq6/6/

This of course if you have to use absolute positioning of the child, because then you would need to add an explicit width. If not, adding `padding: 80px` to the parent will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Wim Mertens. That is extremely close to what I'm looking for. The only problem I can see with your code is that, at 100% width, .resizable is now less wide than in my original jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, that's the whole idea of responsiveness, I'd assumed you'd want to have the square centered in its parent. If you don't care about that you can set a width and/or a min-width/max-width of the child.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to update your jsfiddle with an example of what you mean? If it's what I'm looking for (it sounds like it is) I'll definitely accept your answer :)

Comment: Again, very close but not quite. I probably haven't been clear enough. Like in my original jsfiddle I want .resizable to always be at right: 1% (or some other very low value). Its right edge should stay extremely close to the window's right edge during the resizing

Comment: then remove or adjust the right-padding of the parent like this: https://jsfiddle.net/22rL4eq6/7/

Comment: Yeah that's excellent. Thanks @Wim Mertens. Out of curiosity, is it possible to do exactly that but with only one div and the body (i.e. by removing the .main div)? If it's possible to do without .main then that would be desirable to me.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I would advise to not set width, height or padding to body.

Comment: Sorry, I've been unclear. By that I mean, only using .resizable and body while not adding any extra attributes to body (such as padding) beyond its present height value.

Comment: Ah yes there would be many ways to achieve this with absolute positioning in that case with right: 1%; By default it would be relative to body unless you specify a relative position to a direct parent. Or with floating child divs. Both options have their own issues though.

Comment: Would you mind providing me a code example? It'll be my last question, I promise! (Thanks for being so patient with my questions thus far.)

Comment: ^ That doesn't maintain the space on the left that I've been asking for when resizing